# How to Install OpenCV@2 with Java jars for Java based development

Tags: java, opencv

I tried installing OpenCV2 with java build using the following steps

1. `brew edit opencv@2`
2. set the flag ON `-DBUILD_opencv_java=ON`
3. `brew install --build-from-source opencv@2`

Ideally, this should install OpenCV with Java build and required jars for development.
default path `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.13.2/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-2413.jar`

But it is not generating a jar required for the development.

P.s. I have `ant` as well.

How to install OpenCV with java jar required for development?

Comment: Solved this issue after reinstalling Xode, I hope this helps.